# Excel: add value of column C when column A="text" AND when column B="text"

Tags: microsoft-excel

In column A I have a cities (warehouses).
In column B I have batchorders.
In column C I have amount of products sold of the batch detailed in column B.

When Cell A1 AND A4 is "Madrid" and cell B1 AND B4 is "Batch1" Cell
... should be C1+C4.
If Cell A2 is "Madrid and Cell B2 is "Batch2" cell
... should be B2

Comment: Sounds like you want [`SUMIFS()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: You´re right, thanks Scott!

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6=E1)*(B1:B6=F1),C1:C6)
```

[image]